# error: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: java, android, xml, rss

I am following a youtube tutorial on how to parse RSS feeds into a cardView and recyclerView but keep running into the same issue of the adapter not being attached and I can't find a solution. I have tried matching the code identical to the tutorial but it still doesn't seem to work. Below is the adapter class

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems;
Context context;
public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FeedItem>feedItems){
    this.feedItems = new ArrayList<>(feedItems);
    this.context=context;
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_row_news_item, parent, false);
    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return feedItems.size();
}
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }
}
}
```

Below is my RssReader class:

```
public class ReadRss extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
Context context;
String address = "http://www.sciencemag.org/rss/news_current.xml";
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
ArrayList<FeedItem> feedItems;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
URL url;

public ReadRss(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    this.context = context;
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog.show();
    super.onPreExecute();

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(context, feedItems);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager((new LinearLayoutManager(context)));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    ProcessXml(Getdata());

    return null;
}
```

Followed by main:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    ReadRss readRss = new ReadRss(this, recyclerView);
    readRss.execute();
}
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: you get this error when recycler view does not set any adapter , make sure your Adapter is getting set on the recycler view  and feedItems list is not empty

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few problems with this code. You are not calling `.setAdapter()` until `onPostExecute()`. This is incorrect. Instead, you should add the adapter when your activity is created, and add data to the adapter dynamically. Below is some example code to get you started:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    MyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        ReadRss readRss = new ReadRss(this, recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this))
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter)
        readRss.execute();
    }
}
```

You also need to add a method to your adapter to add new data:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    Context context;

    public MyAdapter(Context context){
        this.feedItems = new ArrayList<>();
        this.context=context;
    }

    public void addItems(FeedItem item) {
        feedItems.add(item);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

}
```

When your asynchronous operations return, use the `addItems()` method to add data to your adapter. Note, I've replaced your declaration of `ArrayList<FeedItem>` with `List<FeedItem>`. This is common practice and allows you to change your list implementation easily.

Comment: I did try these methods as I saw them on another stackover flow answer but none of these seemed to fix the error. Also I replicated the code exactly to the youtubers and his worked fine so I don't understand why mine isn't